# YUV420p is same as YV12

Tags: c#, yuv, color-space

Is YV12 is same as YUV420p? I know that in YV12 the format is like first we have Y Plane then V plane and the U plane. However, in YUV420p we have first Y Plane then u and then V plane.

So the main question is that if we switch u and v planes then can we make the other one?

Thanks

Comment: [Can we can?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T59EDTqqW0A)